# WPF: How to execute a command when a property on the UIElement has changed

Tags: c#, triggers, command

My problem is the following:

I have a `TextEdit` in my view, which has a property `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, which tells me if the keyboard cursor is in the `TextEdit` for the user to type.

On my view model I have a command which I want executed whenever the user has finished typing completely and have clicked somewhere else on the screen. That is - whenever `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is set to false.

I was thinking and the only way I can think of to know when `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` has changed is to use a trigger in the `TextEdit`'s style:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False" />
        <Condition Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

    ???
</MultiTrigger>
```

But I don't know where to place the command and have a strong suspicion I cannot.

Does anyone know if this is possible?
If not, what can you recommend I do?

The entered text is bound to a `string` property, and my command will do different things with it based on what it is.

```
Text="{Binding Path=ChatSessionName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my queston (pretty trivial, but I didn't see it after a long day at work).

As I suspected, Triggers were not the way to do this at all!

It turned out that my TextEdit supports an event **IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged**, so what I needed to do is create a handler which called my command from the code-behind.

```
IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged="TextEdit_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged"

private void TextEdit_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textEdit = sender as TextEdit;
    var viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;

    if (textEdit != null)
    {
        if (!textEdit.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        {
            viewModel.MyCommandExecuted(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another solution I considered was binding **IsKeyboardFocusWithin** to a property on the ViewModel and call the command from inside the setter. 

This seems like a more MVVM-like solution, as it avoids the code-behind, but I didn't like the idea of having a whole property just so that I can call the command.

This said, I would be happy to have a discussion about this.